# Correct Use of $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I am working on an application that includes a web app and a mobile app that sends requests to some of the same php scripts that are used by the web app.

The web app stores some information in the $_SESSION variable when a user successfully logs in and I use that information in the scripts associated with other web pages.  Every script has a session_start() call at the start. All that works fine.

However, when the mobile app logs in (using the same script as the web browser), it seems that the $_SESSION content does not survive after I send a response back to the mobile app since it's not there when the mobile app sends me any further requests.

The mobile app sends its requests as an https:// url straight to my php scripts and includes various parameters appropriate to the script.  It also sets the HTTP_USER_AGENT to a value that allows me to recognize that the request is coming from the mobile app rather than the web app.

Is this the expected behavior?

[EDIT] I've been asked to provide the code in question.  There's a lot of it but here's a snippet of what happens in the login script.

```
$_SESSION['SessionID'] = $sessionid['id'];
$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['UserName']=$username;
$_SESSION['UserRole']=$role
```

There is, of course a session_start() before all this.

Many of my scripts access this info.  The most common use is to check if a user is logged in with the code:

```
if ($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] !==true) {
   < return an error >
}
```

Once again, all these scripts have a session_start at the top.

The above code works fine when connecting from the web browser but always returns an error when connecting from the mobile app.  Printing out the $_SESSION array immediately before the LoggedIn check reveals that $_SESSION is empty.

Comment: I won't downvote, but can you provide the code upon login and how you make use of the `$_SESSION` variable in succeeding pages?

Comment: Sure, I know the code works fine when I connect from my web browser. I will edit the question.

Comment: What is the mobile app written in? What frameworks / SDKs are you using? Sounds like it's not storing the session ID cookie. See http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: when you say "connecting from the mobile app" do you actually mean accessing the site via the mobile device's browser (IE chrome, safari, etc).

Comment: The mobile app is written using Livecode.  It is a standalone app, not a web browser.

I'm thinking this is probably what Phil mentioned about not storing the cookie.  I didn't write the mobile app so will have to check into that.

Have to admit, I didn't understand how the $_SESSION mechanism worked.  SOunds like a cookie is created on the client end containing some sort of id that allows php to get the $_SESSION info from a file on the server.  Do I have that right?